# pass value from xmlhttp to canvas

Tags: xmlhttprequest, html5-canvas

The canvas can't get the value passing from the xmlhttpresponse. Is the order of coding problem? Am I place the canvas in a wrong sequence?
Here is the code I used.

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
str="GT299.842.65.416 2002";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
var result=xmlhttp.responseText;
var n=result.split(" ");
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(n[0],n[1]);
ctx.stroke();
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
 <body>

 <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
 </body>
```

Comment: What does n[0] and n[1] contain?

Comment: it contains an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GET and parse an XMLHttpRequest**

[Edit: to clean up the context drawing code]

First, be sure to add ctx.beginPath() to your canvas drawing code:

```
ctx.beginPath();  // required for all line,curve,arc,path draws
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(n[0],n[1]);
ctx.stroke();
```

Assuming that you have an XML file (myLineXYs.xml) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<lineXYs>
    <line="0">
      <X>50</X>
      <Y>25</Y>
    </line>
    <line="1">
      <X>100</X>
      <Y>25</Y>
    </line>
</lineXYs>
```

You would GET and parse out the X/Y of the 2 lines like this:

```
// IE--there you go again being different!
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  { xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else
  { xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

// GET myLineXYs.xml
xhttp.open("GET","myLineXYs.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

// Parse out the X/Y for the 2 lines
var x0=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("X")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
var y0=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Y")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

var x1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("X")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue
var y1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Y")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Comment: I have get value pass from the php to the varible n. However, the canvas `ctx.lineTo(n[0],n[1])` can't work which a line is not drawn out.

Comment: Yes, please check my edited answer. You need to add ctx.beginPath() before drawing any lines, arcs, curves, paths, etc.  Please forgive, I thought you were asking about getting values through XMLHttpRequest and I forgot to review the other part of your code.